# Trouble deserializing JSON into Java objects with GSON

Tags: java, json, gson, deserialization

I have been trying to learn GSON, but I am struggling with it. I am trying to deserialize a JSON file into Java objects, using GSON. I have read a million other questions on here, and for the life of me, I can't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my JSON text:

```
{
 "movies": [
  {
   "name": "The Shawshank Redemption",
   "url": "https://parsehub.com/sandbox/moviedetails?movie=The%20Shawshank%20Redemption",
   "IMAX": "06:00 PM",
   "rating": "9 . 2",
   "cast": [
    {
     "character": "Andy Dufresne",
     "actor": "Tim Robbins"
    },
    {
     "character": "Ellis Boyd 'Red' Redding",
     "actor": "Morgan Freeman"
    },
    {
     "character": "Warden Norton",
     "actor": "Bob Gunton"
    },
    {
     "character": "Heywood",
     "actor": "William Sadler"
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "Schindler's List",
   "url": "https://parsehub.com/sandbox/moviedetails?movie=Schindler%27s%20List",
   "IMAX": "06:15 PM",
   "rating": "8 . 9",
   "cast": [
    {
     "character": "Oskar Schindler",
     "actor": "Liam Neeson"
    },
    {
     "character": "Itzhak Stern",
     "actor": "Ben Kingsley"
    },
    {
     "character": "Amon Goeth",
     "actor": "Ralph Fiennes"
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

And here is my Java code:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Movies[] movies = gson.fromJson(new FileReader("src/main/input.json"), (Type) Movies.class);
        System.out.println(movies[0]);
    }

    class Movies {
        String name;
        String url;
        String IMAX;
        String rating;
        ArrayList<Cast> cast;
    }

    class Cast {
        ArrayList<CastMember> castMembers;
    }

    class CastMember{
        String character;
        String actor;
    }
}
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.Main$Movies cannot be cast to class [Lcom.Main$Movies; (com.Main$Movies and [Lcom.Main$Movies; are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at com.Main.main(Main.java:13)
```

Comment: I believe the issue is that you are specifying the type as a single Movies.class, which is not the same type as your movies array (which is an array). I'm not familiar with the GSON libraries so I'm not much help, but if you can specify the type as Movies[].class or something similar, that might work.

Comment: If I try changing Movies.class to Movies[].class, I get the following error:  "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $"

Comment: Ah. Make a MovieList class, that has just a list of Movie objects on it. Then use MovieList.class as the type. The JSON you are parsing is an object that contains an array of movies, so your Java object needs to reflect that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON you are deserializing represents an object with a list of objects on it. The Java object you are trying to deserialize to needs to match that.

First, create a new class `MovieList`.

```java
class MovieList {
     List<Movie> movies;
}
```

Update your `Movies` class to be called `Movie`, since it represents a single movie.

```java
class Movie {
     String name;
     String url;
     String IMAX;
     String rating;
     List<Cast> cast;
}
```

Now try calling `gson.fromJson(...)` with the following

```java
MovieList movieList = gson.fromJson(new FileReader("src/main/input.json"), MovieList.class);
System.out.println(movieList.getMovies().get(0));
```

Comment: This solution seems so obvious now that I see it! Thank you very much! Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Movies[] movies = gson.fromJson(new JsonReader(new FileReader("src/main/input.json"))),Movies[].class);
```

or something like

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Movies>>() {}.getType();
List<Movies> movies = new Gson().fromJson(new JsonReader(new FileReader("src/main/input.json"))), listType);
```